# Update one table from another table with duplicate keys

Tags: sql, oracle, merge

I am trying to merge data from one table into another.

Table 1 (Tab1)

```
ID  col2    col3    col_to_update
1   s1      a1      null
2   s1      a2      null
3   s1      a2      null
4   s2      a1      null
5   s3      a1      null
6   s4      a1      null
```

Table 2 (Tab2)

```
ID  col2    col3    col4
10  s1      a1      v1
11  s1      a1      v2
12  s1      a2      v3
13  s2      a1      v4
14  s3      a1      v5
15  s4      a1      v6
16  s4      a1      v7
```

I am trying to map column `col4` from table `Tab2` into column `col_to_update` in table `Tab1` based on matching `Tab1.col2 = Tab2.col2` and `Tabl.col3 = Tab2.col3` to get below expected output:

Expected Output

```
ID  col2    col3    col4
1   s1      a1      v1
2   s1      a2      v3
3   s1      a2      v3
4   s2      a1      v4
5   s3      a1      v5
6   s4      a1      v6
```

I tried unsuccessfully with below query:

```
MERGE INTO Tab1 x1
USING
(
    SELECT  t1.id as t1id, t2.id as t2id, t2.col2 t2col2, t2.col3 t2col3, t2.col4 from Tab2 t2
    JOIN Tab1 t1 ON t2.col2 = t1.col2 AND t2.col3 = t1.col3
) x2 
ON (x1.id = x2.t1id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
x1.col_to_update = x2.col4;
```

Is there a way to get the expected output.

Comment: This doesn't make sense: in the "source" table you have more than one candidate for the value that should be used for the update. WHICH of the potential candidates should be used? In your example, for ID = 1, why did you choose v1 and not v2 from Tab2?

Comment: yes Tab2 has multiple potential matches, I am expecting to map the first or any one that matches.

Comment: "the first" is undefined - is there an order? Or do you mean the min value? Thorsten has already shown how to do that.

Comment: Thorsten's answer has guided me to the required solution. Thank you @mathguy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply want to *update* `tab1`:

```
update tab1
set col_to_update =
(
  select min(tab2.col4) -- or whichever value you want to use
  from tab2
  where tab2.col2 = tab1.col2
    and tab2.col3 = tab1.col3
);
```

Comment: Why do you think this will work? Did you read the question? **Really** read it?

Comment: @mathguy: you are right of course. The request is incomplete, and as there can be multiple matches, we need a rule to determine which value to set. I.e. `select min(tab2.col4)`. I've updated my answer accordingly.